# Passing dynamic list in cut -c

Tags: shell

I have a fixwidth file. Below is the sample:

```
0196969696645001200    1100450000000000TEST1 / TECHNOLOTEST               97827Y
0196969696645001500    1100450000000000TEST222 EXPRESS - CMTEST           97827Y
0196969696600701325    7003150000000000TEST33333                          70215U
0196969696621055400    1476210000000000TEST44444SE - CMC AUERSTEST        97803Y
```

Sample metadata file:

```
COL1,1,2
COL2,3,19
COL3,22,27
COL4,28,33
COL5,34,37
COL6,38,40
COL7,78,81
```

Problem statement: Read meta data file(start and end position)for each column and create one file for each column taking reference of fix width file.

My code:

```
feed_file=$1
metadata_file=$2

 if [ $# -lt 2 ]
  then
   echo "Insufficient Number of Parameters passed"
   echo "Usage <FEED FILE NAME> <META DATA FILE NAME>"
   exit 1
 fi

#Read metadata file and create feed file for each attribute 
 while read line
  do
      attrib_name=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
      beg_point=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
      end_point=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f3`
      echo "$attrib_name || $beg_point || $end_point"

      range=$beg_point-$end_point

      cat $feed_file | cut -c $range > $attrib_name
 done < $metadata_file


Error: cut: bad list for c option
```

Comment: that actually works for me, I can't replicate the error from `cut`. An empty line would give an error on the redirection. But, you could use `while IFS=, read -r name start end ; do...` to split the metadata fields directly, without using `cut` for that

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use shell loops to process text](/q/169716), use text processing tools instead like `awk`:

```
awk -F, '
  !meta_done{start[$1] = $2; len[$1] = $3 - $2 + 1; next}
  {for (i in start) print substr($0, start[i], len[i]) > i}
  ' "$meta_file" meta_done=1 "$feed_file"
```

Note that there's a limitation in that `$meta_file` and `$feed_file` must not be shaped like `awk` variable assignments. If you have files called like `meta=data.txt`, you'll need to pass `./meta=data.txt` to `awk` instead of `meta=data.txt`.